# How to 301 redirect a doamin with a middile page between both domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Want to redirect `www.domainone.com` to `www.domaintwo.com`. I can achieve that using a `.htaccess` file, but I want to show a middle page.

`www.domainone.com` is now `www.domaintwo.com` with 2 seconds of wait.

Using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domaintwo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this will not work to show middle page.

```
header("Refresh:2; url=https://www.domaintwo.com");
```

This will redirect the page but i have 1K url's on [www.domainone.com](http://www.domainone.com) and all need to be 301 redirect on [www.domaintwo.com](http://www.domaintwo.com).

How it can be done ?

Comment: It must be a 301 or can be a 200 and then redirect with JS?

Comment: If I understand you correctly - simply put into your domainone.com/index.html the instructions that the web site has move and a link to the new site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To introduce delay, have a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!delayRedirect\.php)(.*)$ delayRedirect.php?$0 [L,NC]
```

Inside `delayRedirect.php` have this php code to redirect after 2 seconds:

```
<h1>This page will redirect after 2 seconds</h1>

<?php
  header("refresh:2; url=http://www.domaintwo.com/" . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], true, 301);
?>
```

Comment: it's works for single page but what about all other URL that i have on my site. if i use the htacess for other than it will not work :(

Comment: It is matching `.*` in pattern so it it will redirect all the URLs on `www.domainone.com/*` to `www.domaintwo.com/*`

Comment: yes i know but it's redirect all the urls on a single page. i need it like

www.domainone.com/about.html   --- must be redirect --- www.domaintwo.com/about.html

not on www.domaintwo.com

Comment: Okay it works with query string :) Thank you Anubhava

Comment: Indeed this is redirecting to `www.domaintwo.com/about.html` because of `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` in php code and `?$0` in `RewriteRule` that passes current URL as query string.

Comment: when i open the domainone.com without www it does not show delayRedirect.php.. why it happens :(

Comment: If you see condition above it has `^(?:www\.)?domainone\.com$` which makes `www` optional.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not let people hit the domain they are looking for, put the message there and, inside a setTimeout in JS redirect them to where they need to go with something like this on your js file?:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.replace("https://google.com");
}, 3000);
```